# Parse.com sending a push notification to a specific user requires creating a unique channel per user?

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

Just to understand parse.com's push notification system - is a unique channel needed for each user (installation)? It seems push's can only be specified per channel.

Incidentally, is there a maximum number of channels?

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect, you can associate a user with an installation by doing the following:

```
// Associate the device with a user
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

This will put the user in a column "user" in the Installation table, the column would be a pointer to the _User table. You can then target these users for push notifications.